# Android videoView not finding file in R.raw

Tags: android, kotlin, android-videoview

I created the raw resources directory and inserted the video test.mp4 into it.

I am try to run the following code but it is giving me an unresolved reference on test

```
        val uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + R.raw.test)
        videoview.setVideoURI(uri)
        videoview.setOnPreparedListener { videoview.start() }
```

Comment: it should work.. do you have flavours in your app?

Comment: I'm not sure what flavours are

Comment: I had this line in my imports which was messing it up import android.support.compat.R